# sImplexml_load_string doesn't fully load XAdES-BES signature XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've got XML containing XAdES-BES digita signature:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Signatures Id="ID-222cf3cf-0f0b-49d2-b7cb-4cf47bb373cb">
   <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="ID-9a61610b-c8e3-4201-bf41-a174cbc21634">
      <ds:SignedInfo Id="ID-8ebe3e85-1413-4fec-a14c-7264546ab770">
         <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
         <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
         <ds:Reference Id="ID-e751928b-6823-47ad-a5ae-b7ccdf301751" URI="#ID-e37958b8-134c-4f51-9b25-8274fd1edce7">
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <ds:DigestValue>Z7q3zqS5FTNPP/mj0rDmUV5PdZQ=</ds:DigestValue>
         </ds:Reference>
         <ds:Reference Id="ID-396858b0-7e4b-42e1-ba5f-18368f90f0df" URI="#ID-90b9721b-1d1c-4104-ae2c-ebb6b251cf2b" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties">
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <ds:DigestValue>H7EeV4pPoJ6WhWFnVSo3WNu3Yj8=</ds:DigestValue>
         </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue Id="ID-949000f9-85bc-435e-b387-8f7aa5551d75">a0cc/hQYjmwQC8ssBzolLyArUqOVi+s6cP+lbxku69qGleBUroQlvD6o+GpIxSJB6wlWwic3YjuxDxn9
mfW2jCLYEEM1RB277ChnHASakC+vbBP03LWC+GxsOe0seKMVsCc0EPwS5kk5RfvrUN6sTxWSW/2MOIXG
4fW1cAtjh1SjDN9Ij38SIuWpW8guJ9EGEVyTUuTiZ5dbpHfxftgKfHmr16aMpXk0ta46X2UuGTQRB+E/
0W+RpLqdmTP5VG0CxT8Z2H4n6puGL0yC20SsZZDethL/Vnr67EXTPmHFUwoZOGNu+0IFdBJW4HvLA5rF
czL82MOsCoFXqzMVxGxiqw==</ds:SignatureValue>
      <ds:KeyInfo>
         <ds:KeyValue>
            <ds:RSAKeyValue>
               <ds:Modulus>AL4k+zz02RytjonBY0af0dfuuDJhNg0dypClqzkLyyLjkTa9QUbtdtA20lRuogjFqb6CVpqQ/PEdXDK5
bN6qGBQGsmdqkgru6A8aAc57QawEcbEL+rDue1L+mqM/JVnr+DAWOehITd8HzS0JQTQcxF1Lv0L1GNbJ
P8/bo8Coj2EVtKZ9tBI9+AZUdZ11uKBYj9uvKy0VGufjoljIIrQASIft4nw8a/WF+beEYOrl3PqnBcAo
Lc/CJiNsnsASws0a/EKuaP3vQbIo36s7FVH7U4x/8ypcAPsmtgi9LbH+v9Ugc2CiCj7krJIT3X9EwkjC
FUq+MykmVvfW0D0bOTP2X5k=</ds:Modulus>
               <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
            </ds:RSAKeyValue>
         </ds:KeyValue>
         <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>MIIGETCCBPmgAwIBAgIUaQ+g3SS0YfvHQus43mbJ+4FSYegwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwczELMAkGA1UE
BhMCUEwxKDAmBgNVBAoMH0tyYWpvd2EgSXpiYSBSb3psaWN6ZW5pb3dhIFMuQS4xJDAiBgNVBAMMG0NP
UEUgU1pBRklSIC0gS3dhbGlmaWtvd2FueTEUMBIGA1UEBRMLTnIgd3Bpc3U6IDYwHhcNMTUxMDA4MTIw
MDAwWhcNMTYxMDA4MTIwMDAwWjB2MQswCQYDVQQGEwJQTDEbMBkGA1UEBRMSUEVTRUw6IDg2MDYxMzE0
Mzk3MR8wHQYDVQQDDBZLYW1pbCBTZWJhc3RpYW4gTWlqYWN6MRgwFgYDVQQqDA9LYW1pbCBTZWJhc3Rp
YW4xDzANBgNVBAQMBk1pamFjejCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAL4k+zz02Ryt
jonBY0af0dfuuDJhNg0dypClqzkLyyLjkTa9QUbtdtA20lRuogjFqb6CVpqQ/PEdXDK5bN6qGBQGsmdq
kgru6A8aAc57QawEcbEL+rDue1L+mqM/JVnr+DAWOehITd8HzS0JQTQcxF1Lv0L1GNbJP8/bo8Coj2EV
tKZ9tBI9+AZUdZ11uKBYj9uvKy0VGufjoljIIrQASIft4nw8a/WF+beEYOrl3PqnBcAoLc/CJiNsnsAS
ws0a/EKuaP3vQbIo36s7FVH7U4x/8ypcAPsmtgi9LbH+v9Ugc2CiCj7krJIT3X9EwkjCFUq+MykmVvfW
0D0bOTP2X5kCAwEAAaOCApgwggKUMAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwggFPBgNVHSABAf8EggFDMIIBPzCCATsG
CSqEaAGG9yMBATCCASwwgd0GCCsGAQUFBwICMIHQDIHNRGVrbGFyYWNqYSB0YSBqZXN0IG/Fm3dpYWRj
emVuaWVtIHd5ZGF3Y3ksIMW8ZSB0ZW4gY2VydHlmaWthdCB6b3N0YcWCIHd5ZGFueSBqYWtvIGNlcnR5
ZmlrYXQga3dhbGlmaWtvd2FueSB6Z29kbmllIHogd3ltYWdhbmlhbWkgdXN0YXd5IG8gcG9kcGlzaWUg
ZWxla3Ryb25pY3pueW0gb3JheiB0b3dhcnp5c3rEhWN5bWkgamVqIHJvenBvcnrEhWR6ZW5pYW1pLjBK
BggrBgEFBQcCARY+aHR0cDovL3d3dy5lbGVrdHJvbmljem55cG9kcGlzLnBsL2luZm9ybWFjamUvZG9r
dW1lbnR5LWktdW1vd3kwCQYDVR0JBAIwADAhBgNVHREEGjAYgRZrYW1pbC5taWphY3pAZ21haWwuY29t
MA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIGQDCBsAYDVR0jBIGoMIGlgBTMQSp2mC5KehnakTbf2H85P9TCrqF3pHUwczEL
MAkGA1UEBhMCUEwxKDAmBgNVBAoMH0tyYWpvd2EgSXpiYSBSb3psaWN6ZW5pb3dhIFMuQS4xJDAiBgNV
BAMMG0NPUEUgU1pBRklSIC0gS3dhbGlmaWtvd2FueTEUMBIGA1UEBRMLTnIgd3Bpc3U6IDaCFH18c1x7
vNOu01acH+WfGYiAcun0MEAGA1UdHwQ5MDcwNaAzoDGGL2h0dHA6Ly9lbGVrdHJvbmljem55cG9kcGlz
LnBsL2NybC9jcmxfb3prNTIuY3JsMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQAP0zddWprl5hpXiIiMGcC5D7ob
/nj3wvfOUm0QCf7+ZEorfr6EC96B6F/cNtZ1wXtAQXkf5Zm3gPhbKXY6XWM2NDWadZrDV9zV75Ab06dQ
5qmDfuMGTfPUdH3+QBmW7YnniWPCGuMzGNlP9DpZ45YrgRnwlsZSHMhX0HiEeDfYKAkGhIaJ7lcPlZrj
zWBdhUOgYm06pYf8NEKVWzu808iIHIvCBot0ADcZ8ypxDyQsco/RSRGY0EO8FATCH3j2Oe/+7FGRjRQK
XczBsKu6G8GQ6b/eGuWD7NNAuBX4UJu9jXRo9mzo7zKj01/SPfE4kHTHfHr9yi9BBkzAmaAxQpT5</ds:X509Certificate>
         </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
      <ds:Object>
         <xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Id="ID-04b0ddeb-914c-419f-acb2-780dae2ee890" Target="#ID-9a61610b-c8e3-4201-bf41-a174cbc21634">
            <xades:SignedProperties Id="ID-90b9721b-1d1c-4104-ae2c-ebb6b251cf2b">
               <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                  <xades:SigningTime>2015-12-08T13:37:16Z</xades:SigningTime>
                  <xades:SigningCertificate>
                     <xades:Cert>
                        <xades:CertDigest>
                           <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                           <ds:DigestValue>+6UE5SSks6Cn6++o8CAkSO/NMWk=</ds:DigestValue>
                        </xades:CertDigest>
                        <xades:IssuerSerial>
                           <ds:X509IssuerName>serialNumber=Nr wpisu: 6,CN=COPE SZAFIR - Kwalifikowany,O=Krajowa Izba Rozliczeniowa S.A.,C=PL</ds:X509IssuerName>
                           <ds:X509SerialNumber>599792555331422089182929030726347827824527827432</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                        </xades:IssuerSerial>
                     </xades:Cert>
                  </xades:SigningCertificate>
               </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
               <xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
                  <xades:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#ID-e751928b-6823-47ad-a5ae-b7ccdf301751">
                     <xades:Description>Dokument w formacie xml [XML]</xades:Description>
                     <xades:MimeType>text/plain</xades:MimeType>
                     <xades:Encoding>http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#base64</xades:Encoding>
                  </xades:DataObjectFormat>
               </xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
            </xades:SignedProperties>
         </xades:QualifyingProperties>
      </ds:Object>
      <ds:Object Encoding="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#base64" Id="ID-e37958b8-134c-4f51-9b25-8274fd1edce7" MimeType="text/plain">PFRyZXNjUGlzbWE+DQogIDxTeWduYXR1cmFBa3Q+QUJDWFlaMTIzPC9TeWduYXR1cmFBa3Q+DQogIDxQ
b2RtaW90eT4NCiAgICA8UG9kbWlvdD4NCiAgICAgIDxPc29iYUZpenljem5hPg0KICAgICAgICA8SW1p
ZT5KYW51c3o8L0ltaWU+DQogICAgICAgIDxOYXp3aXNrbz5Ob3dhazwvTmF6d2lza28+DQogICAgICAg
IDxPem5hY3plbmllPg0KICAgICAgICAgIDxQZXNlbD44OTEwMDEwMDYxNjwvUGVzZWw+DQogICAgICAg
IDwvT3puYWN6ZW5pZT4NCiAgICAgIDwvT3NvYmFGaXp5Y3puYT4NCiAgICA8L1BvZG1pb3Q+DQogIDwv
UG9kbWlvdHk+DQogIDxQb2RzdGF3YVByYXduYT4NCiAgICA8UG9kc3Rhd2E+UFBfMDA0PC9Qb2RzdGF3
YT4NCiAgPC9Qb2RzdGF3YVByYXduYT4NCjwvVHJlc2NQaXNtYT4=</ds:Object>
   </ds:Signature>
</Signatures>
```

When I load it with simplexml_load_string, var_dump shows:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#212 (1) {
  ["@attributes"] => array(1) {
    ["Id"] => string(39) "ID-222cf3cf-0f0b-49d2-b7cb-4cf47bb373cb"
  }
}
```

There's no nested nodes of "Signatures" data.

However, when I remove "ds" namespaces from tags, it works great.

How can I get them without changing document?

Comment: don't trust `var_dump`, do `echo $xml->asXML();` instead, see https://eval.in/519869

Comment: @michi Output of your script is correct, but I still can't access these nodes, for example: $xml->Signature->Object[1] is null.

Comment: search how to access namespaced elements/nodes with `SimpleXml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the [michi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435626/simplexml-load-string-doesnt-fully-load-xades-bes-signature-xml?noredirect=1#comment58599247_35435626), I found a solution. Namespaced nodes should be accessed differently than nodes without namespace.

So, basing on the example above, when I want to use Signature node, I can do it like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
$signatureNode = $xml->children('ds', true)->Signature;
```